# In Excel, how do I filter for integers, and their corresponding floats?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Let's say I have an arbitrary number of integers that I need to filter, but I also need to get the rows that show their corresponding floats as well, e.g. 10, 12, 20, 31, 42.  With those, I would also need the filter to get 10.2, 10.5, 12.8, 20.3, 31.7, 31.82, 42.1, etc.

What would be the best way to set up a filter for this?

Comment: Set up a helper column where you [round down](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rounddown.php) your values. After that, you can filter them normally

Comment: That's brilliant.  I don't know why I didn't think of that.  I'd gladly mark that as the answer if you put that in here as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a helper column where you [round down](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rounddown.php) your values. After that, you can filter them normally

Syntax: `=ROUNDDOWN( number, digits )`

[image]